# Livebindings master-detail relationship between 2 comboboxes to work vice-versa selection

Tags: delphi, livebindings, tcombobox

I am trying to use the livebindings feature between 2 tcomboboxes having master-detail relationship. Both tcomboboxes are connected to respective datasets. Say, I have a customer name table and the jobs table. Both tables are populated to respective tcomboboxes at runtime.

So far, I do not have issues on one-way populating jobs (detail) upon selection of a customer (master) tcombobox.

On the other hand, I want the tcombobox-jobs (detail), when a value is selected, automatically selects the customer (master).

Is there a way that I can do this with livebindings?

I tried some livebindings setup and I am getting an error.

[LiveBinding Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Lc0.png)

[LiveBinding Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNfgz.png)

I am not really familiar with livebindings yet (how this works at the backend). I will appreciate any help.

Just to let you know, I already tried events to handle this but no success. I am enclined now with livebindings to handle this little function.

Comment: Which customer should it select when you pick a job? There can (in a normal master/detail setup) be multiple customers that has the same job linked...

Comment: @HeartWare It is one customer to many jobs. That when you select a job, there must be one customer only. However, if it select a customer, the user must select which job.